# How to read mixed fractions?

Tags: pronunciation, reading

Is it correct to read mixed fraction 35 466/635 as ' thirty five and four hundred sixty six over six hundred thirty five'?
I know we can read it as thirty five and four hundred sixty six six hundred thirty fifths. But practically it is not possible.  Thank you.

Comment: There is no *correct* way to read something like this.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Then how do English speakers read mixed fractions? For example, when teaching students mixed fractions, how to read them?

Comment: @ramanujan  Both of those are acceptable ways to read *any* fraction.  It's just personal preference.

Comment: @Andrew thanks a lot. I Googled it so much, but nowhere I found satisfactory answer.

Comment: @ramanujan For example, I can read *1/4* and say *one quarter*, *a quarter*,  *a fourth*, or *one fourth*.  There isn't only one correct way of vocalizing the fraction.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Actually my question was particularly for 'mixed fraction'. There are lots of source online on how to read 'common fraction (or simple fraction), but no sources on how to read larger mixed fractions.

Comment: @ramanujan My point is that just like regular fractions, mixed fractions can be read in multiple ways. It can even be converted into a decimal for ease (35.73)—assuming somebody can do that in their head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For larger mixed fractions, such as in your example, where reading the numbers in full results in a sentence so long that it doesn't easily convey that the number is a fraction, some people will simply read it as:

> Thirty five and four-six-six over six-three-five

Since the phrase either side of *over* is relatively short, this is usually clearer.